# Is it possible to cast counterspell while casting a spell with a 1 minute casting time like imprision

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting

I'm a level 17 wizard if that helps you answer the question and im trying to stop vecna from dispelling my simulacrum while im casting imprision on him

Comment: wait but arent i casting 2 spells at once?

Comment: Hello Worldlysage, I've closed this question as a duplicate, it should be covered by the linked question.

Comment: Just changed the dupe link, it should be a much more clear answer to your specific question here.